# Hibernate MySQL Find Unmapped Tables and Columns

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I use Autogenerate DDL feature from Hibernate to create my tables and columns.

However, I end up deleting many columns in my entities but those columns remain in the database.

Is there a script that could identify those unmapped columns and tables so I could manually delete them?

Right now, I do it manually but it's becoming problematic as the database grows.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid you there is no automated way to do that.

Alternatively you can drop the whole table before building and loading the project and let hibernate re-create it with your defined column names.

Comment: Not an option as this is to clean up production tables.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended thing is:

1. We should use the  hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto property only in the development environment, not is the production
2. If hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop, hibernate will drop and create a new database every time of deployment, 
   that means we can track the database state and its consistency.
3. If hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update, hibernate will only update the database with the changes to made in model/entity classes,
   but it should not be trusted for the production environment/database.
4. hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto should be set to default for the production environment, so that no databases changes should be reflected from hibernate in production.

Comment: I agree that prod should never have auto generate ddl. But reality is that i'm stuck with hundreds of unmapped columns that I have to cleanup.

Comment: I'm surprised no one wrote a script for this. As i'm also left with hunder unused foreign keys.